# How to organize parallel processing excluding tasks with the same tag?

Tags: go, parallel-processing

I have a stream of tasks that can be processed in parallel. However, tasks with the same tag must be processed in a FIFO order.

```golang
type task struct {
  tag string
  data []int
}

func process (ch chan task) {
  for t := range ch {
    go processTask (t)
  }
}
```

I need to add logic to prevent processing tasks with the same tag in parallel. Those tasks must be processed in FIFO order.

In 99% of cases the tags are unique. In rare cases several tasks could have the same tag. If we are already processing a task with tag `X` and a new task with the tag `X` appears, we must wait until we finish processing the previous task and then start the next one.

If more than one task with tag `X` is waiting, they must be later processed in the same order as they were sent to the channel.

The processing of tasks with other tags shouldn't be blocked.

What is the recommended way to do it?

Comment: Maybe you want a completely in-process solution, but that doesn't scale particularly well.  If you want to break out of the one-process paradigm, this sounds exactly like an [AWS SQS FIFO Queue](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/FIFO-queues-understanding-logic.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do your FIFO queueing by tag exclusively in process, you probably one one channel and one worker for each tag.  You can track the per-tag channels in a map.

Here's one implementation (https://go.dev/play/p/8r8-oaRaY2x) that's pretty close to being usable for you.  Your actual channel messages could include a results channel.

```
package main

import (
    "sync"
    "log"
)

type Route[T any] struct {
    Input  chan []T
    Output chan T
    Worker func(<-chan T, *sync.WaitGroup)
}

func (r *Route[T]) Accept(wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()
    for inputs := range r.Input {
        for _, input := range inputs {
            r.Output <- input
        }
    }
    close(r.Output)
}

func (cr *Route[T]) enqueue(messages []T, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()
    cr.Input <- messages
}

func (r *Route[T]) Start(wg *sync.WaitGroup) *Route[T] {
    wg.Add(2)
    go r.Accept(wg)
    go r.Worker(r.Output, wg)
    return r
}

func (r *Route[T]) Close() {
    close(r.Input)
}

type Router[T any] struct {
    sync.Mutex
    routes map[string]*Route[T]
    wg     sync.WaitGroup
    routers_wg sync.WaitGroup
    routemaker func(tag string)*Route[T]
}

func (cr *Router[_]) Close() {
    for _, r := range cr.routes {
        r.Close()
    }
}

func (cr *Router[_]) Wait() {
    cr.routers_wg.Wait()
    cr.wg.Wait()
}

func (cr *Router[T]) Route(tag string, messages []T, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    cr.Lock()
    defer cr.Unlock()
    for m, r := range cr.routes {
        if m == tag {
            go r.enqueue(messages, wg)
            return
        }
    }
    new_route := cr.routemaker(tag).Start(&cr.routers_wg)
    cr.routes[tag] = new_route
    go new_route.enqueue(messages, wg)
}

type worker[T any] interface {
    Work(<-chan T)
}

type collateWork[T any] struct {
    work []T
    tag string
}

func (cw *collateWork[T]) Work(c <-chan T, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()
    for w := range c {
        cw.work = append(cw.work, w)
    }
    log.Printf("Worker '%s' collation: %v", cw.tag, cw.work)
}

func main() {

    var routes = Router[int]{
        routes: make(map[string]*Route[int]),
        routemaker: func(tag string) *Route[int] {
            return &Route[int]{
                Input:  make(chan []int, 30),
                Output: make(chan int, 30),
                Worker: (&collateWork[int]{tag: tag}).Work,
            }
        },
    }
    var router_waits sync.WaitGroup
    router_waits.Add(6)
    go routes.Route("a", []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}, &router_waits)
    go routes.Route("b", []int{10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70}, &router_waits)
    go routes.Route("a", []int{8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15}, &router_waits)
    go routes.Route("b", []int{100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700}, &router_waits)
    go routes.Route("c", []int{1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000, 6000, 7000}, &router_waits)
    go routes.Route("c", []int{8000, 9000 }, &router_waits)
    router_waits.Wait()
    routes.Close()
    routes.Wait()
}
```

```
2009/11/10 23:00:00 Worker 'c' collation: [8000 9000 1000 2000 3000 4000 5000 6000 7000]
2009/11/10 23:00:00 Worker 'a' collation: [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15]
2009/11/10 23:00:00 Worker 'b' collation: [100 200 300 400 500 600 700 10 20 30 40 50 60 70]
```